# Can the HomePod be used for VoIP calls?

Tags: audio, call, homepod

Apple mentions that the HomePod can be used for regular phone calls, but would that also work for third party VoIP apps like Skype, WhatsApp etc.?

If this is implemented anything like handoff/continuity for phone calls, my assumption is that it won't work:

While I am able to hand off normal voice calls to my Mac (on the same Wi-Fi), this does not work for VoIP apps, even if they use CallKit (the Mac doesn't show up in the list of target devices, only Bluetooth and wired headsets as well as the phone's speaker show up there).